# onclick radio button active color change using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

when we click on the radio button background color and label color will change I have written CSS but it is not working. I don't want to change my HTML structure with my code only how can I add color to the label on active. Can anyone suggest me.

```js
const handleVisibility = (e) => {
  e.target.closest('.case-inner-info').querySelectorAll('.inner_div [data-ref]').forEach(i => i.style.display = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'block' : 'none');
}
const allOnOffButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div.case-inner-info input");
allOnOffButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleVisibility);
})
```

```css
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  width: 58px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #051326;
  z-index: 2;
}

.switch-input {
  display: none;
}

.switch-input:checked .switch-label {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  -o-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
}

.switch-input:checked+.switch-label-off~.switch-selection {
  left: 60px;
}

.switch-selection {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}

.case-switch .switch-selection {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="case-info" data-ref="on">
        <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" data-ref="off">
        <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-switch">
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-on">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="on" checked>
      On</label>
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-off">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="off">
      Off</label>
      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not do it using CSS alone, if you want to keep this HTML structure. CSS can select downwards the DOM tree and to the right, not upwards or to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this, if this is something resolves your issue, I have removed the `span`

```
<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="case-info" data-ref="on">
        <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" data-ref="off">
        <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-switch">
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-on">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="on" checked>
      On</label>
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-off">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="off">
      Off</label>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const allOnOffButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div.case-inner-info input");
const handleVisibility = (e) => {
  
  e.target.closest('.case-inner-info').querySelectorAll('.inner_div [data-ref]')
  .forEach(i => 
     i.style.display = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'block' : 'none');
     allOnOffButtons.forEach(i => i.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'red' : 'transparent');
}

allOnOffButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleVisibility);
})
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/debraj1983/pen/XWMvqdZ?editors=1111)

Comment: Here I have multiple switches on the same page when I click on any one of the switches then others also  changing.

Comment: Ok, I just followed your code, Can you provide a codepen, I can take a look

Comment: I updated it https://jsfiddle.net/debnathrajdeep/6jnLxc75/10/

Comment: This is what exactly i want here to the parent `case-inner-info` i add ome more class `.pink` so inside this pink class switch bg will be pink and same for different colors. i tried like this `if (e.target.className === 'pink') {
   e.target.closest('div.case-switch').querySelectorAll('input').forEach(i => i.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'pink' : 'transparent');
  }`   which is not working. I have 3 classes pink,blue,green based on parent class switch color change

Comment: It's in the fiddle? I can take a look

Comment: You do this `e.target.closest('div.case-switch').querySelectorAll('input').forEach(i => if(i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref)  i.parentNode.classList.add('pink') else  i.parentNode.classList.remove('pink'));`

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of switch-selection using the position of the label.
But this is not the best solution. You can just use background on switch-label-on and switch-label-off classes and style it like your example using css.

My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Cache the inputs
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.switch-input');

// Add event listeners to them
inputs.forEach(() => addEventListener('change', handleRadio, false));

function handleRadio(e) {

  // Remove the switch-selection class from
  // all the inputs/label background
  inputs.forEach(label => {
    label.parentNode.classList.toggle('switch-selection');
  });

  // And then just toggle it on the radio that's
 // been clicked
  e.target.classList.toggle('switch-selection');
}
```

```css
.switch-selection { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="case-switch">
  <label class="switch-label switch-selection switch-label-on">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="on" checked>
      On
  </label>
  <label class="switch-label switch-label-off">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="off">
      Off
    </label>
</div>
```